# How to check if an HTML file is in a given directory, and then open that file with the referenced CSS and JS files within same directory

Tags: html, node.js, http, fs

For my homework problem, I need to check if a file exists in a certain 
directory "public", and then if it does, open it up through the 
localhost in a browser. I wanted to use a function to check if the file 
exists in directory, and then if true, send the file path to another function that'll open the file. This is all on my server.js file, and the HTML file I want to open along with the CSS and JS for the HTML file are all in my public directory.

This is using node.js. I need to run node server.js in the console, and then go to my localhost in a browser and see the displayed webpage with style and functionality. I've tried using fs.access and fs.existsSync. We are not allowed to use express on this assignment.

```
 var http = require('http');
 var fs = require('fs');

 http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     var filepath = 'public' + req.url;
     if (req.url == '/index.html' || req.url == '/') {
         fs.access(filepath);
    }
 }).listen(3000);
 console.log("Server running on Port 3000...");

 fs.access(filepath, (access) =>{
     if (access) {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        sendFile(filepath, res);
      }
     else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        sendFile('public/404.html', res);
     }  
 });

 function sendFile(path, res) {
     fs.readFile(path, "utf8", function(data){
        res.end(data);
 });
```

}

I'm getting an error that says filepath is not defined (when I use it in the parameters when I call fs.access.

Comment: In your `fs.access` code, where is the `res` objet come from?

Answer (score 0):

fs requires paths with a leading slash to work, so instead of `var filepath = 'public' + req.url;`, try

```
     var filepath = '/public' + req.url;
```